# Create mail in Exchange Online inbox programatically

Tags: exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices

Have been facing an issue since days about EWS. So my scenario is;

I was to programmatically sync GMAIL and EXCHANGE ONLINE. So here is what I have done;

- Connect to Gmail using Gmail API
- Fetch mail from gmail get the email body, to, from,  attachment and
  all other thing
- connect to Exchange online using EWS 2.0

> Now the problem is here, how can I create an email in Inbox which looks like incoming mail from the sender;

Here is the code I have done;

```
_service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        _service.TraceEnabled = true;
        _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("admin@xyz.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
        _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        _service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "xyz@xyz.onmicrosoft.com");

        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(_service);
        Random r = new Random();
        message.Subject = "Email Message";
        message.From = new EmailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
        message.Sender = new EmailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
        message.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, "<HTML><body><h1>This is a voice mail.</h1></BODY></HTML>");
        message.ToRecipients.Add(new EmailAddress(""));
        message.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

This way its creating an email in inbox but it shows as a draft mail. I dont want it, I want it to look as ***RECEIVED*** mail.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a couple of properties **before** saving the message.

```
// Set a delivery time
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagMessageDeliveryTime =
    new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0E06, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
DateTime deliveryTime = DateTime.Now; // Or whatever deliver time you want
message.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagMessageDeliveryTime, deliveryTime);

// Indicate that this email is not a draft. Otherwise, the email will appear as a 
// draft to clients.
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
message.SetExtendedProperty(PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read, 1);
```

These properties aren't settable after the items is saved, so it's important to do it before the first `Save` call.

Comment: Hey Jason, facing one more problem. I want to also create conversations in the EmailMessage. However I see the conversationID property is read only. Is there any way we can do it?